# Current approver of sequential approver workflow

Tags: workflow

We have a standard SP2010 OOB approval workflow on a document library. There are 5 approvers in the workflow. I'm looking for a way to put a new column on document library that show current approver of the workflow. I know you can click the workflow link to see status of workflow but users are looking for a way at a quick glance to show current user (step) of the workflow.

Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plain text or person group column in your document library or create a choice column with all the approvers in it.  Before you create the task in your workflow that assigns the approval to someone, put in an update list action and update that column to the approver.

Comment: You can do this using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Comment: Yes it was a combination of both answers. I knew I needed the update list action but couldn't find were to in approver workflow to added what I needed. I finally found the workflow for task creation and added step to update document library using the list update action and setting it to the assigned to task id.